# Problem with installing 'org.Hs.eg.db' using BiocManager::install in R studio 1.2.1335 & macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: installation, package, bioconductor

Hello I am trying to do Exploratory analysis in R part I (Coursera course). I am using RStudio version 1.2.1335 on macOS Sierra version 10.12.6.

I am having trouble with installing the "org.HS.eg.db" package when I type:

```r
BiocManager::install("org.Hs.eg.db")
```

when it tries to install  "org.Hs.eg.db" I get in the console:

```
installing the source package ‘org.Hs.eg.db’
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.9/data/annotation/src/contrib/org.Hs.eg.db_3.8.2.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 74892843 bytes (71.4 MB) ==================================================
downloaded 71.4 MB
* installing
*source
* package ‘org.Hs.eg.db’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (org.Hs.eg.db) The downloaded source packages are in ‘/private/var/folders/l6/kbsz4n314tdfcxphnmnj7nr80000gn/T/Rtmpb14l6K/downloaded_packages’
```

When I then later try to run:

```r
chr = AnnotationDbi::select(org.Hs.eg.db,keys=aeid,keytype="ENSEMBL",columns="CHR")
```

I get in the console:

```
Error in AnnotationDbi::select(org.Hs.eg.db, keys = aeid, keytype = "ENSEMBL", : object 'org.Hs.eg.db' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `library(org.Hs.eg.db)` first?

Installing the package is not enough. When you want to use functions / objects from a package you need to load it in your R session using `library()`:

```r
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
chr <- AnnotationDbi::select(
  org.Hs.eg.db,
  keys = aeid,
  keytype = "ENSEMBL",
  columns = "CHR"
)
```

This should work, assuming you have the `AnnotationDbi` package installed and have an object called `aeid` defined in your R session.

You might want to check out some tutorials on using R and R packages, such as [this one](https://moderndive.netlify.app/1-getting-started.html#packages).

---

**Additional remark not related to your question:**

- note that *RStudio* and *R* are [2 very different things](https://moderndive.netlify.app/1-getting-started.html#r-rstudio). RStudio is an IDE, software that you use to interact with R code. R is the programming language itself. So it makes more sense to mention the **R version** you're using instead of the RStudio version.
- In this case it might also make sense to mention the version of *BioConductor* you're using (you can check this with `BiocManager::version()`.
- It's better practice to use `<-` for assignment in R (for example what you're doing to create `chr` in your example). `=` is generally reserved to specify function arguments